# Javascript. Замена значений в квадратных скобках

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
текст текст текст текст [id1|Павел Дуров] текст текст текст текст
```

либо

```
текст текст текст текст [club123456|Звукозапись] текст текст текст текст
```

Подскажите, как на JS, заменить её на вид:

```
текст текст текст текст <a href="http://vk.com/club123456">Звукозапись</a> текст текст текст текст
```

По сути регулярка, которая через эту ф-цию ищет оба слова и подставляет их:

```
str = "aaa aaa aaa aa [club123456|Клуб любителей] ааа ааа ааа";
str.replace(/первая и вторая строка/, function(found) {
  if (found[found.length - 1] == "|") {
    return "<a href='http://vk.com/'" + found + ">"
  } else {
    return found + "</a>";
  }

})
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение `/\[(.+?)\|(.+?)]/g`

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "aaa aaa aaa aa [club123456|Клуб любителей] ааа ааа [id1|Павел Дуров] ааа".replace(/\[(.+?)\|(.+?)]/g, function(_,$1,$2) {
  return '<a href="http://vk.com/'+$1+'">'+$2+'</a>';
})
```